# google analytics ga() command queue

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to understand GA tracking code logic. In particular how the ga() function actually works. Can someone please help point to the code in the snippet that picks up the items in the command queue and executes them. And also the new commands.

"The JavaScript tracking snippet defines the initial ga() command queue function, so it can be used even before the analytics.js library is fully loaded. As soon as the analytics.js library is loaded, the items in the command queue are executed in the order they were received. Once this is done, new commands pushed onto the queue are executed immediately."

Comment: The snippet is just a loading script. The actual logic is in the analytics library that is loaded by  the snippet, and since this is heavily obfuscated looking for a specific bit will probably not be very enlightening.

Comment: But if I were to use the debugger to follow the execution of ga command queue commands, would it be possible to piece together the logic. There must be some place in the analytics javascript where whatever is pushed in the ga command queue is popped and processed and sent to the google analytics server. That is the piece I am looking for.

Comment: @Aging yes it's possible to piece it together. I'd start by unminifying/prettyfying the analytics.js file, but you will have a rats nest of unreadable so it will be tedious and time consuming. If you are trying to implement similar functionality I'd open a question describing the functionality you want, and what you have tried.